# Can my 300W power supply handle this graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I want to but this graphics card:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IDG3IDO/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IDG3IDO)

It says it requires  300W or more.

My power-supply is 300 max.

Does anyone know If I will run into issues if I buy this?

Comment: It should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [EVGA GeForce GTX 750 Ti Superclocked](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-3753-KR) product page:

```
Requirements

Minimum of a 300 Watt power supply.
Total Power Draw : 60 Watts
```

So your power supply is *just enough* according to the manufacturer.

Depending on your PC configuration, it might not be able to deliver enough power.

Specifically, if you have a lot of power using devices in your PC (primarily hard drives), then you may experience problems under heavy load.

Another thing to consider is if your current power supply has the necessary auxillary power plugs which your graphics card might need. These are typically 6 or 8 pin connectors labelled PCI-E, like these:

[image]

I cant find information on, whether or not the graphics card in question needs a PCI-E power connector, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Off the top of my head the *50s are typically PCIe powered.

Comment: The card in question isn't going to draw 300W, the suggested wattage is the overall system use, the 750 cards use around 55-65w chips.

Comment: According to the FAQs on Amazon, this model does not require an external power supply. It only requires the power from the 16x connector to the mother board.